# Android Action Bar with Tabs

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I'm trying to make an app with an action bar and tabs. The user should be able to swipe between the tabs. Each tab has different content (via fragments).

What is the best method to use? 
How can I make sure the app works with  Froyo?

Comment: You can use ViewPager to create sliding tabs, I'd recommend you to support from android 4.0 because I don't think you get much features with Froyo. You can follow [this](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html) tutorial i made on sliding tabs but its based on android 4.0 and above so I'm not sure whether it would work on froyo or not. your only gonna lose 7.3% of android users anyway :D

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. I'm using eclipse btw

Comment: Your Welcome, Why not use Android studio? :D

Comment: Afraid of change perhaps but i will soon enough...If it's better